# two finger double tap zoom in any app

Tags: macos, trackpad

Is there a way to enable two finger double tap on Trackpad to zoom not only in browsers, but also in anywhere else on the computer? Currently it only works for browsers.

I am running osx El Capitan.

Comment: There's no standard way to zoom an application. Do You want something similar to CTRL+scroll ? http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/112879/ctrl-scroll-zoom-on-mavericks-gone

Comment: The exact same used to happen with 2 finger double tap. Hmmm